# How do I set up a jabber server that supports jingle?

Tags: server, xmpp

I want to be able to video chat with jabber, what jabber servers support jingle?

Answer (score 0):

Server support is not required for Jingle, as the clients communicate directly and only use the XMPP channel for negotiating.